# How to switch View without using app.navigate() in Kendo UI mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I would like to use custom routing schemes so I can not use `app.navigate()`.

How can I switch Views (remove other Views from DOM, move header and footer to selected View, etc.) without using `app.navigate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you can't do that without modifying the Kendo UI source. The mobile app gets attached to the router instance and will react to the location changes. You may consider forking the Kendo UI Core repo and implementing the detached mobile application mode - in this way you should be able to use the app.navigate without changing the location.

Comment: What does `app.navigate()` exactly does? As I understand, it removes unused views from DOM and moves header and footer to current view (I'm using tabstrip). What else?

Comment: not really - views are not removed from the dom but hidden, in order to perform the transition effects. You may check the source code for more details - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.mobile.pane.js#L189